# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tslib". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, npm, fullcalendar, node-modules

please, I started learn npm. If I want instal "@fullcalendar" and used it i get error: "*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tslib". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*"

**I have this structure:**
www/templates/node_modules/
www/templates/assets/calendar.js

**It is start of my calendar.js file:**

```
import {Calendar} from '../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.js';
import dayGridPlugin from '../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js';
import timeGridPlugin from '../node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.js';
import listPlugin from '../node_modules/@fullcalendar/list/main.js';

other code
```

In the moment where is imported {Calendar} its throw error. In @fullcalendar/core/main.js i see:

```
import './vdom';
import { __extends, __assign } from 'tslib';
import { render, createElement, CalendarRoot, CustomContentRenderContext, CalendarContent, flushToDom, DelayedRunner, CalendarDataManager, isArraysEqual, applyStyleProp, CalendarApi } from '@fullcalendar/common';
export * from '@fullcalendar/common';
```

But i think that way to tslib (and other import libs) is incorrect. But tslib is in directory www/templates/node_modules/tslib . I dont want edit installed package (i think that is not correct way). Can I set path in npm config? It is possible? Or what is the best way?

Thanks,
A.

Answer (score 1):

Your imports are wrong. You don't need the full path to your node modules. You can import them like:

```
    import Calendar from '@fullcalendar/core';
    import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
    import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
    import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it was default setting. But i get the same error: "*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@fullcalendar/core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*"

Comment: What framework are you using? Are you using react? Do you have package.json file? Did you install any packages in your project or are they global packages?

Comment: I use only jquery for this project. My package.json file is: https://pastebin.com/L8NeKLfg .  Mayby i must install some autoload package ...

Comment: For that case, this article might be really helpfule for you: https://medium.com/@collectiveacuity/how-to-setup-a-jquery-project-as-a-node-module-50abbc274113